# php array echo specific key value

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I wrote a function to `echo` the value from each key `name` out of an array. Is there a nicer, shorter way to write following code?

```
foreach ($prod_cats as $k1 ){
    foreach ($k1 as $k2 => $value){
        if ($k2 == 'name'){
            echo $value;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example on how my array looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [term_id] => 11
        [name] => example1
        [slug] => example1
    )

    [1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [term_id] => 12
        [name] => example2
        [slug] => example2
    )

    [2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [term_id] => 13
        [name] => example3
        [slug] => example3
    )
)
```

Comment: `array_map(function($v){ echo $v->name;}, $yourArray);`

Comment: `foreach ($prod_cats as $k1 ){echo $k1->name;}`

Comment: @JohnConde Did you ate a semicolon in your code :)?

Comment: fantastic John Conde ! It works and is short :) Would you like to add your comment as an answer below?

Comment: Thanks to Rizier123 too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you know name keyword is fixed and available, you can avoid one more loop.

```php
foreach ($prod_cats as $k1 ){
    echo $k1['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_walk()`

```
array_walk($input, function($obj){ echo $obj->name; });
```

This can be done with `array_map()`, but when you are not creating a new array out of your current array, `array_walk()` is suggested, because, it doesn't return anything, while `array_map()` returns an array conatining what is returned by function passed to it as a callback.